# One entity and Multiple DB table

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Is there any way to store one JPA/Hibernate entity into many database tables?

For example there is a way to store inherited entities (more than one type of entity) in a single database table, my question is just reverse of this.

Comment: You might be able to handle this at the database level by using triggers.

Comment: perhaps look up JPA "Secondary Tables" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can store one entity in multiple database tables. Just annotate your entity class with @SecondaryTable / @SecondaryTables and use the 'table' property of your field mapping annotation to map the field to a column from a specific table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="TABLE1")
@SecondaryTables({
    @SecondaryTable(name = "TABLE2", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "ID")),
    @SecondaryTable(name = "TABLE3", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "ID"))
})
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID") /* when no table property is given, the primary table is used which is TABLE1 */
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "FIELD1", table = "TABLE2")
    private String field1;

    @Column(name = "FIELD2", table = "TABLE3")
    private String field2   
}
```